# c++ source code formatter

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, formatting

I am searching for a lib or a method which gets a string of c++ source code as input and tiddys up the source code, like indenting lines and so on.
Is there already a Lib, or method which does this or do I have to implement it myself? If so how should I implement this? writing a whole parser sound like an overkill for me.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441917/are-there-any-lint-tools-for-c-and-c-that-check-formatting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier